# Filtering in tweepy - exact phrase

Tags: python, tweepy

I can't get tweepy filtering to quite work how I want to.
stream.filter(track=['one two' , 'three four'])

I want to retweet based on a specific two word set
i.e. "one two"

but I'm getting retweets where the tweet has those two words, but not in order and separated
i.e. "three two one" or "one three two" etc.

I want tweets which contain my phrase but in order
i.e. "one two three" or "three one two" or "one two" etc.

Comment: Why can't you post-process the stream you receive? pseudocode: `if any(x in tweet.text for x in ['one two', 'three four']): retweet(tweet)`

Comment: You should also provide an example of your code (being careful to remove any developer keys!)

Answer (score 0):

the twitter api doesn't allow that. you'll have to check for each returned tweet whether or not it actually contains one of your exact phrases.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use quotes and escape them

```
stream.filter(track=['\\\"one two\\\"' , '\\\"three four\\\"'])
```

I did test it with the cursor and its parameter q

Source:
https://twittercommunity.com/t/correct-syntax-for-an-exact-phrase-match-and-keyword-query/124617